# How to List out feeds from face book in timeline format

Tags: android, facebook

I have to do a small android application. It should connect with facebook and have to post feeds into wall and retrieve feeds to display in timeline format. I am new to android and fb. Could any one help?

Comment: Look up facebook connect as a starting point

Comment: Hi.. I did finish my task by using fbconnect. Its works nice. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Official Android SDK for Facebook](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)